APL - idiomatic way to filter, group, and sort from matrices
I am attempting to learn APL, but I am having a hard time writing code in an idiomatic way.
Part of the problem, I believe, is that it is hard to find teaching material sufficiently broad and complete.
For instance, consider the following problem: we have a matrix with n rows and 3 columns. Assume that all columns are of the same type. We want to obtain a vector of vectors of the elements on the second column, grouped by the value of the first column, and sorted by the value in the third column.
So, for instance, for the input matrix
1 A  1
1 B  3
2 F  5
2 B  2
1 C  8
1 D 10
2 D  9
2 E 13

we would like the output to be
┌────┬────┐
│ABCD│BFDE│
└────┴────┘

I came up with:
{1 ⌷[2]¨{(⍵[;1] {⍺ ⍵}⌸ ⍵[;2 3])[;2]} {↑(↓⍵)[⍋⍵[;3]]} ⍵}
which works, but I am certain that there is a much easier, elegant, and idiomatic way to do this in APL.
How would you do it?

input← (⍪1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2),(⍪'ABFBCDDE'),⍪1 3 5 2 8 10 9 13
{↓x[;1]⊢⌸2⌷[2]x←⍵[⍋⍵[;3];]}input
{x[;1]⊂⍤⊢⌸2⌷[2]x←⍵[⍋⍵[;3];]}input ⍝ fixed to reflect requested output format

Assume ⎕IO←1.

We want to obtain a vector of vectors of the elements on the second column, grouped by the value of the first column, and sorted by the value in the third column.

It is easier to achieve that by sort the input before regrouping using ⌸ since it is good to know the order is preserved during regrouping.
While this behvavior is intuitive enough to be inferred from experimenting with this operator, the language reference clearly says.

The elements of R appear in the order in which they first appear in Y

⊢⌸ is equivalent and shorter form of {⍵}⌸, of course.
(And ⊂⍤⊢⌸ equivalent of {⊂⍵}⌸)
Now, I have formed my solution independently, let's find what is the difference.
It seems you have observed the behavior of ⌸, then just be aware
that for the input data type of this problem,
{↑(↓⍵)[⍋⍵[;3]]} ←→ {⍵[⍋⍵[;3];]}
And it is rare for idiomatic APL code to nest dfns (aka anonymous function). So just open it:
{1 ⌷[2]¨{(⍵[;1] {⍺ ⍵}⌸ ⍵[;2 3])[;2]} ⍵[⍋⍵[;3];]}

If you don’t remove abstraction in APL code, you will lose the opportunity to seek further optimizations. The next function application can also be opened using local variable
assignment,
{1 ⌷[2]¨(x[;1] {⍺ ⍵}⌸ x[;2 3])[;2]⊣x←⍵[⍋⍵[;3];]}

Now, since only the grouped data instead of index key is needed
for the result, remove the redundancy altogether by keeping the
data lean and efficient at first place:
{(x[;1]{⊂⍵}⌸ x[;2])⊣x←⍵[⍋⍵[;3];]}

And squeeze the result a little bit it would be identical to the solution I developed or went for a different method for simplification.
{⊃⊂⍤⊢⌸/↓⍉⍵[⍋⍵[;3];][;1 2]}


Thank you! This helps a lot explaining the spirit behind the language. One thing though: I noticed that the behavior of your solution is slightly different from mine. For the input
input← (⍪1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1),(⍪'ABFBCDDEG'),⍪1 3 5 2 8 10 9 13 20
my original solution returns
| ABCDG│BFDE |
while yours is
| ABCDG│BFDE  |
And there is as extra space in the second cell. The intended behavior would be the first. How would you adjust your solution?

@MarcoPegoraro {x[;1]⊂⍤⊢⌸2⌷[2]x←⍵[⍋⍵[;3];]}input, i.e., change ⊢⌸ to ⊂⍤⊢⌸ which is equivalent of {⊂⍵}⌸

Another approach, using the leading axis oriented Index function to select the columns from the transposed input:
input← (⍪1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2),(⍪'ABFBCDDE'),⍪1 3 5 2 8 10 9 13
{↓(1⌷x)⊢⌸2⌷x←⍵[;⍋3⌷⍵]}⍉input

Index selects the rows (the rank 1 elements of ⍵) and acts as LdBeth's [;1 2] and then group the characters by the first row of digits.

Thank you! The index glyph nicely visualizes the three separate steps of the code. As in the solution from LdBeth above, the behavior of your solution is slightly different from mine. For the input
input← (⍪1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1),(⍪'ABFBCDDEG'),⍪1 3 5 2 8 10 9 13 20
my original solution returns
| ABCDG│BFDE |
while yours is
| ABCDG│BFDE  |
And there is as extra space in the second cell. The intended behavior would be the first. How would you adjust your solution?

Removing the extra space has a couple of choices - either change Key's function to {⊂⍵} or remove the space at the end in each cell via ' '~⍨¨ So {' '~⍨¨↓(1⌷x)⊢⌸2⌷x←⍵[;⍋3⌷⍵]}⍉ or {(↓(1⌷x)⊢⌸2⌷x←⍵[;⍋3⌷⍵])~¨' '}⍉
Having trouble finding the ouput difference after fixing that - and APL's having trouble too:
1≡({1 ⌷[2]¨{(⍵[;1] {⍺ ⍵}⌸ ⍵[;2 3])[;2]} {↑(↓⍵)[⍋⍵[;3]]} ⍵}≡{(1⌷x){⊂⍵}⌸2⌷x←⍵[;⍋3⌷⍵]}∘⍉)input
